# How do I generate a json object and send via PUT request from Rails app to Shopify API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, shopify

I'm just getting started with the Shopify API (within a Rails app) and this is my first API integration I've done. I feel like there's something incredibly basic I'm missing, and that the documentation assumes I know.

Documentation - http://docs.shopify.com/api/order.html#update

I'm just trying to update attributes on an Order (really any attribute. I just need to prove I can both read from and write to the Shopify API).

I installed the Shopify_App gem (https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app) which made the OAuth process really simple, and am able to view all my orders and call extended info to Read, but when it comes to a Write I'm lost.

Do I need to create a bunch of json templates and interface through JS? Should I be writing a custom Action in my Controller? Hope this is a 30-second "oh, duh!" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is for the RESTful API which is language/framework agnostic.

The gem (which is the way to go if you are using Rails) uses ActiveResource so to invoke that PUT request you just need to [update](https://github.com/rails/activeresource#update) the order and save.

Comment: These were the exact words and the exact link I needed to hear. Thank you so much BBG!